# Is there any other way to find the intersecting line between the following 2 planes?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given a pyramid $T.ABCD$ where $ABCD$ is a square. See the following figure.

[image]

$L$ and $K$ are midpoints of $TA$ and $TC$ respectively. The line intersecting plane $TBD$ and $BKL$ is need to draw.

## My attempt

$B$ is one common point shared between the planes in question. We need one more common point to draw the required intersecting line. Using symmetric, the midpoint of $LK$ (denoted as $M$ in the following figure) is the second common point. As a result, $BM$ is the intersecting line.

[image]

## Question

Is there any other method (maybe without using symmetric) to draw the line?

Comment: What do you mean "without symmetry"?

Comment: @Moti: Without symmetric in mind such as assuming the base is not a square for example.

Comment: @Moti: Wording is not easy for me as I am not a mathematician by design. To makes it clearer, the other method in question must not directly or intentionally use the midpoint $M$.

Comment: Well, if you know the points (x,y,z) B, D, T - you have the plan equation. With K, L, B you have the other plan equation. The two plans define your line.

Comment: @Moti: Using analytic geometry is not allowed.

Comment: The direction of the line is the cross product of the plane normal vectors.  Can you use this fact, or does "analytic geometry not allowed" exclude this?

Comment: @J.Heller: Only drawing with a compass, pen, and straight edge is allowed.

Comment: The methods used in _Descriptive Geometry_ allow to construct the intersection of arbitrary planes or to decide that the intersection is empty. Start with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_geometry, for example.